# How to write jquery append $("#id").append() statement if element id is defined as a php function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am building a website and a webpage contains same elements with element id which is created by a php function so that element id will be unique.
I want to use a jquery append statement to add div element with id created by a php function.How to write jquery append statement?

**HTML PART:**

```
  <div id="q2s<?php the_ID(); ?>">          
  <span class="t2"><input type="text" class="t2" id="t2s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  </span>   <span id="star2s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating2"></span>   
  <hr></div>
```

In html part `<?php the_ID();?>` is the php function used for getting unique id

**JAVASCRIPT PART:**

```
  <script>
  var getstarid="<?php the_ID();?>";//php function for getting unique id
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var q2 = $("#q2s"+getstarid);//This is the part i am asking 
                              //about.How to write this statement?  
  $(q2).append('<div id="q2s<?php the_ID(); ?>"<span class="t2"><input 
  type="text" class="t2" id="t2s<?php the_ID(); ?>"></span>   <span 
  id="star2s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating2"></span><hr></div>');
  });
  </script>
```

in javascript part `var getstarid="<?php the_ID();?>";`is used for getting unique id.

How to write `var q2 = $("#q2"+getstarid);`in jquery so that element id can change and jquery append can work according to change in value of php function `<?php the_ID();?>`?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What you've done will work (although you'll end up with invalid duplicate `id` attributes, but that's a separate problem) however you're missing the `s` in the Id. `var q2 = $("#q2" + getstarid);` --> `var q2 = $("#q2s" + getstarid);`. I'd also suggest you look in to using common classes to group elements as dynamically generated/incremental ids often become a big pain to maintain, generally speaking

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.This php code is actually part of a plugin file for wordpress and the php function the_ID() is part of that plugin.So i have to use the_ID() for this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,also what is  "invalid duplicate id attributes" problem?

Comment: This means that you can only have one element in the DOM with a given `id` attribute. In your code it looks like you're creating multiple elements with  `id="q2s<?php the_ID(); ?>"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,will that create any problems?

Comment: It will if you try and select any of those elements by their `id` - you'll only ever be able to get the first one

Answer (score 0):

With something like this, I usually embed the code/id/whatever in a data attribute in an element on the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="q2s" data-id = "q2s<?php the_ID ?>">
```

Then I retrieve it in my javascript using the jquery "data" method:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  var getstarid=$("#q2s").data("id");
  ...
  var q2 = $("#q2s"+getstarid);//This is the part i am asking 
                              //about.How to write this statement?  
  $(q2).append('<div id='+getstarid+'><span class="t2"><input 
  type="text" class="t2" id="t2s"'+getstarid+'></span>   <span 
  id="star2s'+getstarid+'>" class="rating2"></span><hr></div>');
  });
```

This benefits you in two ways, potentially: 1 - It's cleaner.  You shouldn't be putting PHP code mixed in with your javascript.  2 - It might save you some database access.  I don't know if PHP hits the database every time it hits "".  This way, it only calls that function once and then lets jQuery do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Will this still be creating elements with unique id?I mean,div id is given as q2s only,so will it create any problems?

Comment: @codewiz - No, the HTML above would not create unique elements if it is in a PHP loop of some kind.  To do that, you would still revert back to your <div id="q2s<?php the_ID(); ?>">.  But I would still keep using the data-id attribute to hold that ID, as well.